# Jupyter magic command %%time buggy in conda virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I use jupyter notebook with a python 3.6 installation. I created an anaconda virtual environment, and when I launch a jupyter notebook inside it, the %%time command seems buggy.

If I write a cell with the %%time command like follow :

```py
%%time
a = 2
```

All my variables declarations are unknown in my following cells

```py
print(a)
```

I get the following error :

```
NameError                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3f786850e387> in <module>
----> 1 a

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

However, it works just fine in my root environment. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour was changed in iPython 7.3 to work in this way:

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time

So I assume that your root environment must have an older version of iPython / Jupyter notebook.

Alternative option:

```
import time
start = time.time()

"the code you want to test stays here"

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks. Do you know any command which acts like %%time in previous versions ?

Comment: I've added an alternative to the answer. Not as nice as the magic unfortunately.